# Embedding PDFs through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat

I am trying to programatically embed PDF files to specific worksheets. When I embed using the ClassType variable "Adobe.Document.2015", the file opens without problems, however, I have to manually paste in the filepath. When I embed using the filename argument of OLEObjects.Add, I can do it programmatically, however, when the user opens the PDF document embedded this way, they get an error message on the Acrobat side. This message does not appear when adding through the ClassType argument of OLEObjects.Add. Is there a way to use both ClassType and Filename arguments so I don't have to manually paste the file paths?

I am at a loss as I have attempted Application.SendKeys but it is executed after the OLEObjects.Add method is resolved, not during. Appreciate any help.

[Adobe Acrobat Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaHLn.png)

```
Sub OLE_Objects_Fix()

Dim OLE As Excel.OLEObject
Dim OLEs As Excel.OLEObjects

Dim Xl As New Excel.Application
Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim dirPath, fileName, filePath As String
Dim Rng As Excel.Range

Set Rng = Summary.Range("A1")

dirPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\...\Models\"
fileName = VBA.Dir(dirPath, vbNormal)

With Xl
    .Visible = True
    While fileName <> ""
        If VBA.Left(fileName, 9) = "unique identifier" Then
            Debug.Print fileName
            Set Wb = .Workbooks.Open(dirPath & fileName, False, False)
                For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets
                    Ws.Activate
                    Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0)
                    If Ws.Name = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                        filePath = Rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    End If
                    For Each OLE In Ws.OLEObjects
                        OLE.Delete
                    Next OLE
                        If filePath <> "" Then
                            Debug.Print Ws.Name: Debug.Print filePath
                            Set OLEs = Ws.OLEObjects
                            Set OLE = OLEs.Add( _
                            fileName:=filePath, _
                            Link:=False, _
                            DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                            Left:=Ws.Range("F1").Left, _
                            Top:=Ws.Range("F1").Top)
                        End If
                Next Ws
            filePath = ""
            Wb.Close (True)
        End If
        fileName = VBA.Dir
    Wend

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: But, in what program do you work, only using Excel object? Where do you need to manually paste the file path?

Comment: @FaneDuru I am working in Excel. When I use the ClassType argument in the OLEObjects.Add method, it opens a file dialog and requests me to select a file. I have tried using Application.SendKeys but it is executed after the method is resolved, not during, as I need.

Comment: Then, `Dim Xl As New Excel.Application` is a strange approach... Anyhow, if your OLEObject will be embedded **as icon**, will that be a problem? I am asking that with a purpose...

Comment: @FaneDuru I am using a new instance of excel to open those workbooks because I do not want a user to see the OLE Objects being updated. if I used the active instance of Excel, their user input may mess something up. Displaying the item as an icon instead is not of concern to me as long as the document still opens without error.

Comment: OK. Then try this: In fact, I will post an answer. You will not understand it here, in the comment...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, please, replacing your piece of code for adding OLEObject with this one and let me know if it is well open:

```
Set OLE = OLEs.Add( _
    fileName:=filePath, _
    Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
    IconFileName:= _
     "C:\Windows\Installer\{AC76BA86-1033-FFFF-7760-0E0F06755100}\_SC_Acrobat.ico", _
     IconIndex:=0, _
     IconLabel:="Click to open the " & Ws.Name & " PDF file")
```

A second version not needing the icon path. It uses the (installed) exe path. And **it also shows the associated application icon**. There are two ways of doing that. Using API or extracting it directly from Registry. I will show a sample only for the first way:

Adapt your code to create the OLEObject in this way:

```
   exePath = exeApp(filePath)

    Set OLE = ws.OLEObjects.Add( _
            fileName:=filePath, _
            link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
            IconFileName:=exePath, _
            left:=ws.Range("F1").left, _
            top:=ws.Range("F1").top, _
            IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:="Embeded PDF (your name)")
```

Put the API function on top of your module (in the declarations part):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindExecutable Lib "shell32.dll" _
                 Alias "FindExecutableA" (ByVal lpFile As String, _
                 ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal lpResult As String) As Long
```

And copy the function able to retrieve the associated application path:

```
 Private Function exeApp(strFile As String) As String
       Const MAX_FILENAME_LEN = 260
       Dim i As Long, buff As String

       If strFile = "" Or Dir(strFile) = "" Then
          MsgBox "File not found!", vbCritical
          Exit Function
       End If
       'Create a buffer
       buff = String(MAX_FILENAME_LEN, 32)
       'Retrieve the name and handle of the executable
       i = FindExecutable(strFile, vbNullString, buff)
       If i > 32 Then
          exeApp = left$(buff, InStr(buff, Chr$(0)) - 1)
       Else
          MsgBox "No association found, for this file !"
       End If
    End Function
```

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. I've taken a look and my C:\WINDOWS\Installer\ directory does not contain {AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AB0000000001} folder. I will search for the PDFFileIcon file instead.

Comment: I've found the icon file and ran the code, but it returned a 1004 error, "cannot add object". I've tried inserting an argument for IconIndex as 0 or 1 as well, however it did not solve it.

Comment: It works for me... And I use this way of embedding from a lot of time. With exact the same IconFileName path for more then four installation... Without checking if it exists, or it would be a different one...

Comment: Try searching for "pdffile_" in the Installer folder, please...

Comment: Try replacing of that ico file (in the same folder) with `SC_Reader.ico`...

Comment: What Adobe installatiion do you use for pdf file opening? I am using Adobe Acrobat DC...

Comment: I am using Adobe Acrobat DC as well. I was able to locate the pdf file icon and insert the file, but the icon does not display. Instead the OLE Object is blank, but it opens without errors so it works.

Comment: I am trying now to look for the exe file using `FindExecutable` API and do it in a different way... If I will have something better, I will post it here.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've edited your code to show how I arrived at the solution. I used the _SC_Reader.ico you suggested in combination with an IconIndex argument.

Comment: I do not see the edited part... And I was not notified about such an edit. Now I see it. **This I just wanted to suggest!**

Comment: @Marat_Muginov: I also updated my answer with a solution able to automatically determine the application exe path, according to (any) application associated to .pdf extension. It also adds a icon to the embedded pdf file.